# Redirect from IonMenu to a page using Ionic React

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework, redirect, routes

I created a menu with React in Ionic Framework and I want to redirect to the page that user clicked but this doesn't happen, items are not clickable. I already tried with IonButton instead of IonItem and that works properly!

```
    <IonMenu side="start" contentId="content">
      <IonHeader>
        <IonToolbar>
          <IonTitle>Menu</IonTitle>
        </IonToolbar>
      </IonHeader>
      <IonContent id="content">
        <IonList>       
          <IonItem routerLink="/Home">
                <IonIcon slot="start" icon={home}></IonIcon>
                <IonLabel>Home</IonLabel>
          </IonItem>    
          <IonItem routerLink="/Activities">
                <IonIcon slot="start" icon={bicycle}></IonIcon>
                <IonLabel>Activities</IonLabel>
          </IonItem>
          <IonItem routerLink="/Login">
                <IonIcon slot="start" icon={exit}></IonIcon>
                <IonLabel>Logout</IonLabel>
          </IonItem>
        </IonList>
      </IonContent>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a reference to the *IonRouterOutlet*, pointing the same id that you have in the attribute *content* and define all the routes matching the menu.

```
<IonApp>
  <IonReactRouter>
    <IonSplitPane contentId="content">
      <Menu />
      <IonRouterOutlet id="main">
        <Route path="/Home" component={Home} exact={true} />
        <Route path="/Activities" component={Activities} exact={true} />
        <Route path="/Login" component={Login} exact={true} />
        <Route path="/Logout" component={Logout} exact={true} />
        <Route path="/" render={() => <Redirect to="/Home" />} exact={true} />
      </IonRouterOutlet>
    </IonSplitPane>
  </IonReactRouter>
</IonApp>
```